# Let's make an awesome wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have just come across [this post on Meta SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279847/302377), which speaks of a really awesome wiki in the [help-center of the Buddhism site](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help).

It reminded me of [Quora's Data Science wiki](https://www.quora.com/topic/Data-Science) which includes a really good step-by-step guide to Data Science.

Having such a nice wiki helps us re-direct the `getting started` posts to the wiki, so that the users can self-help themselves to a certain extent which helps reduce low quality content as well as helping the new users/learners (Win-Win!).

But, compiling a wiki of that quality requires good and active community participation. So, do chip in with ideas and posts.

Hint: We can try to get an idea of the wiki from the(and not just limited to,) [beginner](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tag on the main site.

After we have a consensus of the wiki, the mods can go ahead and create it (as underlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279848/302377)).

Let's have the discussions related to the wiki construction in the [DataScience chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40597/data-science).